# Change primefaces split button values with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, web, primefaces

I have created the following split button with primefaces :

```
<h:form style="text-align: right;" >
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <p:splitButton value="My Profile" actionListener="#{userLogin.myprofile}">
        <p:menuitem value="Log In"  url="http://localhost:8080/xhtml_files/login.xhtml"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Sign Up" url="http://localhost:8080/xhtml_files/signup.xhtml"/>
    </p:splitButton>
</h:form>
```

In my web development project I successfully validate users and check if they are logged in or not. 
I want to change menuitems values when a user is logged in , and change it to something like that:

```
<h:form style="text-align: right;" >
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <p:splitButton value="My Profile" actionListener="#{userLogin.myprofile}">
        <p:menuitem value="Log Out" actionListener="#{userLogin.logout}" />
    </p:splitButton>
</h:form>
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to change it with javascript???

Comment: This is just HTML; the fact that you're using primefaces shouldn't matter. Just turn the various elements visible or invisible, depending on your application state.